# How could I set up the Rails app under sub-domain with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app start from `https://sample.co/browse/`

the `https://sample.co/` will redirect to another web app.

I got the `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/browse"):`

How could I set my Rails config to get rid of `ActionController::RoutingError`

Thanks ~

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/tmp/puma.sample.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server{
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8006;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /sample {

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://app;

        }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are trying to deploy app on sub uri and not on subdomain.

Here are few resources which will help you,

https://gist.github.com/coffeencoke/4422617

http://abhionrails.com/ruby/rails/capistrano/nginx/deploy/sub/uri/passenger_base_uri/route/scope/2013/10/20/Deploying-a-Rails-app-to-a-Sub-URI/